# two jquery functions that interfere with one another

Tags: jquery

I have 2 jquery functions that do something similar (one for mouseover, the other on click) and they seem to be interfering with each other.  The first changes the background using the jquery ui switchclass on a hover.  This also bring a submenu up.  When you click on a link in the submenu it fires an click function that removes the previous menu.  and uses switchclass to change that background.  The problem is as soon as you move your mouse it fires the mouseout and changes the background back to the default background.

This is the mouseover.

```
     $('.hoverbg').mouseover(
  function(){
   var newimg = $(this).attr('data-bgsrc');
   $('#bg img[src="'+newimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
   $('#bg img[src!="'+newimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
  });
$('.nav').mouseout
 (function(){
    if ($('#sitewrapper').hasClass("c"))
    {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    }
    else
    {
      $('#bg img[src="images/bg.jpg"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
      $('#bg img[src!="images/bg.jpg"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
    }
  });
```

Here is the click event.  it hides the nav class that is part of the mouseout.  technically i guess that has made you mouseout of that menu, but i have it add a class to the sitewrapper div and stop if the class is present.

```
    $('a#navclick').click(function(){
 var iclick = $(this).attr('data-iclick');
 var clickimg = $(this).attr('click-data-bgsrc');
 if ($('#topId').hasClass('.topOn'))
 {
   $('#bg img[src="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
   $('#bg img[src!="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 }
 else
 {
 $('#sitewrapper').addClass("c");
 $('img.logo').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
 $('.nav').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
 $('#bg img[src="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 $('#bg img[src!="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 $('#topId').addClass('topOn');
 $('#topId').show("slide", {direction:"up"}, 1000);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it figured out.  The click function was fine it looks like this;

```
    $('a#navclick').click(function(){
 var iclick = $(this).attr('data-iclick');
 var clickimg = $(this).attr('click-data-bgsrc');
 if ($('#topId').hasClass('topOn'))
 {
   $('#bg img[src="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
   $('#bg img[src!="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 }
 else
 {
 $('#topId').addClass('topOn');
 $('img.logo').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
 $('.nav').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
 $('#bg img[src!="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 $('#bg img[src="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 $('#topId').show("slide", {direction:"up"}, 1000);
 }
 });
```

The hover function needed an if statement to stop it once a click happened.  So i had the click event add a class to a div that becomes visible called topOn.  then added an if statement that checks if that div has a class of topOn.  It looks like this;

```
     $('.hoverbg').mouseenter(
  function(){
   var newimg = $(this).attr('data-bgsrc');
   $('#bg img[src="'+newimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
   $('#bg img[src!="'+newimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
  });
$('.hoverbg').mouseleave
 (function(){
   if(jQuery('#topId').hasClass('topOn'))
   {
     jQuery('.hoverbg').stop();
   }
   else
   {
    $('#bg img[src="images/bg.jpg"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
    $('#bg img[src!="images/bg.jpg"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
   }
 });
```

Comment: I may be wrong, the click parameters contained in the else section don't seem to change the images in firefox and explorer.  ANy thoughts as to why just that doesn't work?